# Catching errors from a form within PHP

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and I am  trying to achieve the following. If any users click the submit button it will check the php file, if an error is found then it should stop executing and display the error message or continue.

The code I currently have is:

```
<?php include('mobile_check.php'); ?>
<div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
<div class="mobile-grids">
    <div class="mobile-left text-center">
        <img src="images/mobile.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-right">
        <h4>Enter your mobile number</h4>
        <label>+91</label><input type="text" class="mobile-text" name="req_number" value="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" required="">
    </div>
    <?php echo $mobileError; ?>
</div>
<ul class="list-inline pull-right">
    <li><button type="button" name="mob_submit" class="mob-btn btn btn-primary next-step">Next</button></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And my php code is

```
<?php   
if( isset($_POST['mob_submit']) ) { 
    if (empty($req_number)) {
        $error = true;
        $mobileError = "Please Enter Mobile No.";
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]{10}+$/",$req_number)) {
        $error = true;
        $mobileError = "Please Reenter correct no.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you format the code so i dont have to scroll, thanks.

Comment: "stop executing and display the error message or continue." so when does it stop and when does it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 option that you have is exceptions such as:

```
try {
    if( isset($_POST['mob_submit']) ) {
        if (empty($_POST['req_number'])) {
            throw new exception("Please Enter Mobile No.");
        } else if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]{10}+$/",$_POST['req_number'])) {
            throw new exception("Please Reenter correct no.");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Within the try block if an exception is thrown it will immediately jump to the catch block. In the sample provided I have simply echo'd the exception message.

Comment: i really should use try\catch more.

Comment: Its not working... if i am clicking on submit button it is going on next step though req_number is empty

Comment: The form is it using post or get. Easiest way to tell is if the URL it submits too show say ?req_number=0 in the address bar. Also I have updated my code. I guess you have not supplied the full php but the variables for the form inputs were not being taken from the $_POST superglobal. If you are actually using get ensure to change each $_POST to be $_GET instead.